# py2exe error when running exe file

Tags: python, py2exe, openpyxl

I have successfully converted .py file to .exe file using py2exe. 
I can successfully run the .py file,if i run it standalone.However, when iam trying to run the .exe file, it throws an error as seen in attached image.

In my .py file, i have the below import statements:

```
import xlrd,xlwt,xlutils.copy,re,time,openpyxl,os
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

I have also accordingly tweaked setup.py file to include these packages as below setup.py code shows

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['vu_t2.py'],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': ['xlrd','xlwt','xlutils','openpyxl','openpyxl.workbook']
        }
    }
)
```

Please refer the attached error snapshot[image]

I used the below command to run py2exe

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Comment: First of all delete all *.pyc and check the line 475 in your vu_t2.py file if there is any error there. Then try to rebuild your .exe file.

Comment: vu_t2.py woks successfully without any error.I get error only when running the exe file.

Comment: Well i cannot help you a lot with only those informations. But i recommend you to look again in your setup.py and read this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Answer (score 2):

openpyxl only supports distribution via `pip`.

Comment: I did not understand...what do you mean to say?Request you to kindly clarify

Comment: You are trying to package and distribute openpyxl as an executable Windows file. This is not supported.

Comment: Is there an alternative by which i can make my executable work?